# Edit an OWL Individual using OWL API

Tags: ontology, owl-api

I have an ontology created in protege 4. I need to add a data property to an owl individual of my ontology using OWL API 4. i am new to java / owl api so to my understanding. i used following code:-

```
OWLNamedIndividual myowlIndl = df.getOWLNamedIndividual(":test", pm);
OWLDataProperty indlName = df.getOWLDataProperty(":strVal", pm);
OWLDataPropertyAssertionAxiom dataPropertyAssertion = df.getOWLDataPropertyAssertionAxiom(indlName, myowlIndl,"hello world");
AddAxiom addAxiom1 = new AddAxiom(myowlOntology, dataPropertyAssertion);
myontologyManager.applyChange(addAxiom1);
```

but this code do not "Update" already existing owl individual "test" but create a new one.

How to rectify this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the full IRI instead of a shortened version, it is hard to tell from this code whether the namespace is the correct one (":test" is ambiguous, since we cannot see how the prefix manager resolves it, and we cannot see the ontology).
Also, make sure to save the ontology after the call to applyChange().

Comment: Thanks alot. playing with the IRI did the trick. by the way. whats the difference between using iri="file:/D:/university.owl" and iri="http:/localhost:3030/university.owl" ?

Comment: One is a document IRI that depends on the physical location of the ontology, the other is a URL that stays constant and is not tied to a specific file system path - it allows you to move the files around and still refer to them with the same IRI, provided that the server at localhost:3030 knows where to find the content. Also, the URL can be imported by someone else in their ontology, while your local file is only accessible to you.

Comment: Thanks for the question & answer. Unfortunately i don't want to add a new Literal added to the existing DataProperty instead I would like to modify an existing Literal. Do you have an idea how to solve this?

Comment: Use a RemoveAxiom to remove the old value and an AddAxiom to insert the new value. OWLAxioms are immutable objects so there is no way to change a part of one.